# Problem bringing string part in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having a problem getting string part in ElasticSearch. Below is the configuration of index.

```
PUT exemplo
{
    "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "portuguese_br": {
          "type": "portuguese"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "content": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "portuguese_br"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is a document with the following content in the index "exemplo":

```
h2 style margin 0 0 8px font size 16px color 064a7a 1 Síntese Resumo Descrição do cliente h2 div id headertipodocumento1 style min height 40px position relative class editable mce content body contenteditable true spellcheck false p eu encaminho uma Carta ao ReI
```

I can't get the document with the following request:

```
GET exemplo/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"regexp": {"content": ".*caminho.*"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

There is a part of content with the word "encaminho". I'm searching for "caminho" and not getting any result.

Am I doing something wrong in regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand **how Elasticsearch analyzes your text** you can use the following API.

```
GET exemplo/_analyze
{
"text": ["h2 style margin 0 0 8px font size 16px color 064a7a 1 Síntese 
  Resumo Descrição do cliente h2 div id headertipodocumento1 style min 
  height 40px position relative class editable mce content body 
  contenteditable true spellcheck false p eu encaminho uma Carta ao ReI"],
"analyzer": "portuguese_br"
}
```

The output of `encaminho` part will be like the following:

```
{
  "token" : "encaminh",
  "start_offset" : 236,
  "end_offset" : 245,
  "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
  "position" : 38
},
{
  "token" : "cart",
  "start_offset" : 250,
  "end_offset" : 255,
  "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
  "position" : 40
},
{
  "token" : "rei",
  "start_offset" : 259,
  "end_offset" : 262,
  "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
  "position" : 42
}
```

After the analyzer **encaminho** text is transformed to **encaminh**, when you search **caminho** it's not matching with **encaminh**.
What you can do?

1. You can search as you indexed (look additional notes)
2. You can add an [ngram analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) feature into your existing
   analyzer
3. You can use fuzziness queries during the search

Additional notes:
Data analysis is performed during indexing. But data is not analyzed during the query because you are using a wildcard (regex) query. If you can use a match or multi_match your queries will match. Also, match queries are faster than wildcard queries.

```
GET exemplo/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content": "encaminho"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The token generate in field content for term "encaminhado" is "encaminh". When you try search by term ".*caminho.*" there is no match.

If you try  {"regexp": {"content": ".*caminh.*"}} you get the document.

Another option is fuzziness. Like this query:

```
   {
      "match": {
        "content": {
          "query": "caminho",
          "fuzziness": "AUTO"
        }
      }
    }
```

That way you will also get results.